# How to set nodejs version in azure

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, devops, angular7

I'm deploying angular 7 app to Azure using bitbucket, I'm using this script in `package.json`

`"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-ng": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
"engines": {
    "node": "8.11.1"
  },`

and set Application directory to

> site\wwwroot\dist\myapp

but it failed, here is the log

[Running deployment command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB08s.png)

I've deployed angular 5 app to Azure in the same way previously and it works fine

**Updates**

I've set the default node and npm version in `package.json` and add them as default variable in Application setting
so the new errors is
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RI43.png)

Comment: Hi Kenada, welcome to S.O!!  How are you deploying your code to azure? Are you using some kind of functionality like heroku? What is the s.o of your box in azure?

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz well, I don't use heroku, I'm only execute this script in `package.json` , by defualt, there is default deployment command from kudu that is executed

Comment: @JRichardsz I've updated the post, pls have alook

Comment: I can see in your log, you use windows as server. My first advice is : Windows is not the best choice to work with nodejs. Linux box or a minimal linux docker container is the best choice to work with nodejs in production

Comment: According to your log, you need a dependency. Try this : **npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular**

Comment: Thanks @JRichardsz I've added it to **dependencies** and it works, but a new problem appear `FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory angular` Do you have any idea? Or Should I add a new post for it?
I think it' due to `budgets` settings

Comment: You are welcome. Yes you are right. A new post is required.

Comment: Also, you could update your question to : How set nodejs version in azure box configurations or something like that? Because, your initial question was fixed with some configurations not related to nodejs. Am I right?

Comment: It's done @JRichardsz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was adding 
**WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION** in Application setting string, even adding

`"engines": {
    "node": "8.11.1"
  },`

in package.json have no effect, another solution is to add **issnode.yml** file and to project file
and add this command to it
`nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.11.1\node.exe"`

Comment: I had zero luck with the app setting. Adding the `yml` file with the `newProcessCommandLine` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are running version v0.10.40 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6 and above.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.

Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find the instructions on how to update Node.js

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have specified node version in `package.json` and set "engines" to "8.11.1", I've updated the post

Comment: so don't know Why this error is appear!, even I choose node version, and at the beginning in the log you van notice that the selected node version is 8.11.1